# A word for the ability to refer to something

Tags: word-request

If something is able to fly, then they say that it is flyable.

If something can be copied, then they say about it that it is copyable.

I need a word to express the ability to refer to something or someone.

Maybe **referable**?

I'm also looking for a reverse word to express the ability to be something that can be referred to.

[image: reference]

Comment: Can you give a context where this would apply? I'm struggling to think of something that cannot be referred to, but if I could, the correct word might occur to me.

Comment: "referable" is in dictionaries: "capable of being referred".  It seems to be mostly used medically "This is a referable condition, and so we will refer you to the specialist in London".  I agree with gotube,  an example in context  is needed.  I don't get what the chart is supposed to mean.

Comment: _Flyable_ means _able to be flown_ (like a plane), not _able to fly_ (like an animal).

Comment: You could have a look at [this](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reference/) or read a book on semiotics and semiology.

Answer (score 3):

The word you are looking for is not '*referable*' because that is something capable of being *referred*, not referenced. One refers *to* something as a point of reference.

The word would be *referenceable*.

The word isn't used often in everyday speech but it is a valid word (my Grammarly has no issue with me typing it right now). You may find it used more in the field of computer programming in the context of items stored in reference libraries etc.

Comment: What is difference between "referred" and "referenced"?